Probability of an $AABbCC$ offspring given the cross $AaBbCc\times AaBbCc$, is my solution correct?
So I have been working through the drills in the 26th edition of AP Biology Prep by The Princeton Review for fun when I came across this question in the Chapter 12 drill that I'm not really sure about my answer to:


Given the cross $AaBbCc\times AaBbCc$, what is the probability of having an $AABbCC$ offspring?(A) $\dfrac14$(B) $\dfrac18$(C) $\dfrac1{16}$(D) $\dfrac1{32}$


Here's my thinking:
I can draw up 3 Punnett squares to calculate the probability of having an $AA$, then a $Bb$, and finally a $CC$ offspring, as then due to the law of probability, I can then multiply these probabilities together to get my final answer, right?
So we have the three Punnett squares:
$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c|}
  & A  & a  \\ \hline
A & AA & Aa \\ \hline
a & Aa & aa \\ \hline
\end{array}\\
\\
\begin{array}{c|c|c|}
  & B  & b  \\ \hline
B & BB & Bb \\ \hline
b & Bb & bb \\ \hline
\end{array}\\
\\
\begin{array}{c|c|c|}
  & C  & c  \\ \hline
C & CC & Cc \\ \hline
c & Cc & cc \\ \hline
\end{array}
$$
So from our Punnett squares, we have a 25% chance of the offspring having the AA gene, 25%+25%=50% chance of the offspring having the Bb gene, and then a 25% chance of the offspring having the CC gene.
So, due to these observations, the probability of this cross resulting in an $AABbCC$ offspring should be $1/4\times1/2\times1/4=1/32$, and (D) is the correct answer.
My question is: Is my thinking correct, or is my answer wrong, and why if so?

Yes, it is correct.

In the case of no linkage, yes.

@MaximilianPress What do you mean by linkage? I've never heard of it.

Linkage is the non-independence of transmission of alleles at different loci. It is traditionally understood to mean when two loci (e.g. the A locus, or B or C loci, from your example) are physically close to each other on the chromosome. This leads to distortions because it is unlikely that recombination will reassort alleles from those 2 loci. There are also other phenomena that can lead to linkage. I strongly recommend any genetics text to learn more.

Your thinking is indeed correct. Just from probability, if you know the odds of 3 separate events, multiplying them together will give you the % chance of all 3 occurring. Putting this whole thing into a single punnet square is also possible which gives us a 2/64 chance, or 1/32 as the answer choice says. If I were taking an exam I would use the same thinking as you. 

Sorry about the late comment @Snow, but welcome to Bio.SE! This is a great first contribution, and I hope you enjoy your stay here! I actually would like to provide some feedback about the giant Punnett square: While I do find the idea interesting, wouldn't this be super inefficient to use when taking a test? Or is that why you said that you'd use the same thinking as me during a test?

Hello @CrSb0001, thanks for your friendly remarks. Yes apologies if I was not clear enough but when I said I would use the same thinking as you in an exam I mean precisely that I would just multiply the separate odds together to get the total. Even drawing a 2x2 square in an exam is not particularly useful unless in strange cases such as X or Y chromosome problems, where they can be very helpful. My 8x8 monstrosity was just to help give you the full picture and to act as proof of your idea. I would never use that in an exam setting. Good luck with the AP biology prep!

Thanks, although I'm just doing it for fun lol
